# Need an efficient way for a simple problem in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a web application using c#. I am reading some data from database to a data table named dt . Sample data is shown below.

```
agentName  WeekNumber Score 
John       3          45
John       5          78
John       6          33
```

I want to make some change in the above data based on some conditions. Cause i want to draw a graph based on this data.The agent name is always same.and the week field is unique. I want to make a new data table using conditions listed below.

1-The new data table week field must start from 1.If there is no entry in the data table for week 1, you can add the data into new data table as shown below

```
John 1  0
```

it means just give 0  as score.

2-If there is any missing weeks from second row onwards in the data table obtained from database , add the row for that week with score as -1.
in the above example after first row there is a missing week 4. so add it to new data table with score -1

the new data tab;e for sample data is shon below

```
agentName WeekNumber Score
John      1          0
John      2          0
John      3          45
John      4         -1
John      5         78
John      6         33
```

How can i do it in an efficient method using c#? The number of rows will vary .
I want to do it using c# . not by using queries because of some reason

Comment: So what do you call "efficient": You want to minimize the network traffic, disk usage, use memory efficient, or do you want the best performance on a system with thousands of concurrent users?

Comment: Do you really want to add this entries or just to sum them afterwards? Because the solution for the second thing would be possible (and maybe even easier) without these "dummy entries".

Comment: Have you tried something and found it not efficient enough?

Comment: I am looking for a solution which is  memory efficient and have a faster execution. Some times the data table size will be big- arround 600 rows

Comment: @MatthiasG I really want to add these entries

Comment: @Shameer: Have a look at the answer from Binary Worriers. It looks suitable and efficient for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following class and the build a new table from it.

```
class AgentsData
{
    public static DataTabe ProcessDataTabe(DataTable dt)
    {
        Dictionary<string, AgentData> data = new Dictionary<string, AgentData>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string name = dt.rows[i][0].ToString();
            if (!data.ContainsKey(name))
                data.Add(name, new AgentData);
            int week = Convert.ToInt32(dt.rows[i][1]);
            int score = Convert.ToInt32(dt.rows[i][2]);

            data[name].Add(week, score);
        }

        foreach (vat agentData in data.Values)
            agentData.Process();

        //now build new data table from dictionary and return it
    }   
}

class AgentData
{
    public AgentData(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        WeekScore = new Dictionary<int,int>();
    }

    public void Add(int weekNumber, int score)
    {
        WeekScore[weekNumber] = score;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        int min = WeekScore.Keys.Min();
        int max = WeekScore.Keys.Max();

        for (int i = 0; i < min; i++)
            WeekScore.Add(i, 0);

        for (int i = min + 1; i < max; i++)
            if (!WeekScore.ContainsKey(i))
                WeekScore.Add(i, -1);
    }

    public string Name {get; private set;}  
    public Dictionary<int, int> WeekScore { get; private set;}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a table in the database with default values for every week in a year.
Left Join on this table when selecting out your resuls and take the default value if the other is missing.

e.g.

```
select 
    dt.name, 
    def.week_no, 
    (case dt.value is null then def.value else dt value end) value
from 
    def left join dt on def.week_no = dt.week_no
```

Code untested, but should take everything from the default table, and rows from dt table where they exist. If the dt row doesn't exist it will take the default value.

Where dt is your existing table with values, and def is the table with a default value for each week.

Comment: There is no default value, sometimes it is 0 and sometimes -1.

Comment: +1 Itay and i want to do using c# , not by using queries . :( Thank you

Comment: If you would let execute this query from the db server you could be sure that it will be very "efficient". And if you join it to a list of all possible weeks and know which on is the first "real" entry, you can decide if you have to insert 0 or -1. edit: oh, no queries :( Apart from the fact that the solution above could be realized by using linq.

Comment: @MatthiasG: I think that the first "real" entry may vary per agent.

Comment: @Shameer, this is c#. the query syntax is part of c#.

Comment: @Itay, @Shameer: You didn't say anywhere you only wanted C# solutions, forgive me but you said "I am reading some data from database", and you said you want the most efficient way to do this. As you're hitting the database anyway this is by far 1) The simplest way to do this and 2) The most efficient. You're already using "queries", just use them a little smarter :)

Comment: @itay: there's a default value for each week, the first week is 0, the rest are -1. It's all in how you look at the problem.

Comment: @Binary Worrier: This is not how understood it, never mind :P